# Unable to enable a button in Activity after custom adapter Edit text afterTextChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-adapter

Within this project MainFragment, Custom Adapter classes are used for load listview. The adapter items are populated from a bean class named 'PayMode'. In that adapter there are four 'TextView' and one 'EditText (allocatedAmt)'. That 'EditText' is not populated from that bean class. AfterTextChanged on that 'Edittext' Logcat is properly display the text 'editable.toString()'.

Now I need to enable a button (in MainFragment) afterTextChanged listner for that 'Edittext(allocatedAmt)' in adapter. Below is my code.

**Adapter.java**

```
public class PayModeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PayMode> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<PayMode> list;
    boolean isAllocatedFinished = false;

    public PayModeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PayMode> list ) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_pay_mode, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    public boolean isAllocatedFinished() {
        return isAllocatedFinished;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        View row = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        final PayMode payMode = list.get(position);

        if (row == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_pay_mode, parent, false);

            holder = new Holder();

            holder.mode = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPayMode);
            holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPayDate);
            holder.amt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
            holder.remAmt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtRemAmount);
            holder.allocatedAmt = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.editAlloAmount);

            holder.allocatedAmt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    isAllocatedFinished = true;
                    Log.d("PAY_MODE_ADAPTER", "VALUE_IS: " + editable.toString());

                }
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (Holder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.mode.setText(payMode.getFPAYMODE_PAID_TYPE());
        holder.date.setText(payMode.getFPAYMODE_PAID_DATE());
        holder.amt.setText(payMode.getFPAYMODE_PAID_AMOUNT());
        holder.remAmt.setText(payMode.getFPAYMODE_PAID_AMOUNT());
        holder.allocatedAmt.setText("0.00");

        return row;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView mode;
        TextView date;
        TextView amt;
        TextView remAmt;
        EditText allocatedAmt;
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
onCreateView(){
payModeArrayList = new PayModeDS(getActivity()).getAllPayModeDetails();
        payModeAdapter = new PayModeAdapter(getActivity(), payModeArrayList);

        if (payModeAdapter.isAllocatedFinished()){

            bCancel.setEnabled(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `holder.allocatedAmt.setOnFocusChangeListener` and override its `onFocusChange` method.

inside `onFocusChange` add below code

```
if(!hasFocus) 
{
//your changes here 
}
```

Hope that helps